# How can I see my full reputation in SE flair after 10k?

Tags: support, reputation, combined-flair

After reaching 10,000 reputation, our Stack Exchange flair shows only our reputation based on thousands. How can I see my full reputation in my flair instead of "10k"?

[image: Flair Image]

Comment: I think you can only see it on your profile page and the notification bar then.

Comment: Even if you could get this, the value would be heavily cached....

Comment: Does the combined flair ever show the full reputation? Even below 10k is still only shows it in the form X.Xk