# combined flair tooltip looks broken because img title uses `&amp;` instead of ampersand

Tags: bug, combined-flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flair is double escaping some Turkish characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160285/flair-is-double-escaping-some-turkish-characters)

Bug can be seen at this user flair page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-gonul/flair

When hovering over user's combined flair tooltip shows `&#246;` instead of `ö` (see screen shot below).

This page also shows how to do it right - ordinary flair tooltip is displayed OK.

The difference looks like caused by img `title` attribute using `&amp;` in combined flair instead of ampersand that works fine in ordinary flair. Tested with Firefox and IE.

- snippet of combined flair code:
  `title="profile for Soner G&amp;#246;n&amp;#252;l on Stack Exchange..."`
- for the reference - snippet of ordinary flair code:
  `title="profile for Soner G&#246;n&#252;l at Stack Overflow..."`

Note that `alt` attribute in combined flair code appears to have the same issue.

---

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zstzs.png]

Comment: bug was discovered when I hovered over user flair in [another meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160284/how-can-i-see-my-full-rep-in-se-flair-after-10k)